# Restricting range in a box plot in Python with matplotlib and seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm hitting a wall with this problem on an assignment. Likely have been looking at this for too long to see it.

Next look at the lotarea data. Create a box plot of lotarea and see that there are outliers above a lot area of 50k. Create a Series that contains only lotarea rows where the lot area value is <=50k. Create a box plot of this series.

I have sns.boxplot(y="saleprice", data=prices_df)

data set info in the doc
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ISC0S04rogKz_-h8IB9TxGU4pUrBYeNPpo8fG3oVVI0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please provide the dataset? or at least the commands to load it?

Comment: Can't you provide the dataset directly? I'm not going to log into an unknown sql server…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult to answer without the actual data, but assuming the column you want to filter on is "saleprice" and the price data is a unit integer (50k = 50000), try something like:

```
sns.boxplot(y="saleprice", data=prices_df.query('saleprice < 50000'))
```